# When does fgets start reading?

Tags: c

If I were to print a prompt to stdout:

```
printf("> ");
```

and then I said

```
fgets(tester, 80, stdin);
```

would fgets read the whole line including the "> " or would it start after that?

Comment: Neither.  Data written to `stdout` are not ordinarily available for readback from (the same process's) `stdin` at all.

Answer (score 5):

The prompt is **output** (on `stdout`). `fgets` is reading **input** from `stdin`. So no, it won't read your prompt.

Your terminal displays `stdout`, `stderr` and `stdin` all together, but that doesn't mean there isn't an underlying distinction between them.

`stdout` is typically  *line buffered*, and `printf("> ");` lacks a *new line*, so the output may not appear on a terminal display until later.  `fflush(stdout)` to insure it is outputted before the `fgets()`.

```
printf("> ");  
fflush(stdout);
fgets(tester, 80, stdin);
```

Comment: Further clarification: Your terminal displays `stdout`, `stderr` and `stdin` all together, but that doesn't mean there isn't an underlying distinction between them

Comment: @Alexander: Well put. Feel free to just edit that in (even if it weren't a community wiki answer, but particularly as it is).

Answer (score 0):

The fgets won't read anything because the printf will write on STDOUT and not on STDIN.

Answer (score 0):

No. `printf` will reflect the `stdout`. It will never effects your `stdin`. The `str` buffer will reflect all the characters you give as an input after `>`.

Test for the same can be done like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

char str[80];
printf(">");
if( fgets (str, 60, stdin)!=NULL ) 
   {
      puts(str);
   }
   return 0;
}
```